# Prelude to Cauchy-Schwarz, Quadratic proof.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have a problem in trying to prove the following observation: "Show that if $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} $ are such that for all $ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} $, $a\lambda^2 + b\lambda +c \geq 0 $ then $ b^2 - 4ac \leq 0 $." I know that this is elementary since is the graph of a parabola possibly above the $\lambda$ axis. But when I try to do an inequality approach I cannot seem to see it.

My work: Since it works for any $ \lambda $ I choose $ \lambda = - \dfrac{b}{2a} $ and I get:
$$ \dfrac{a \cdot b^2}{4\cdot a^2} - \dfrac{b^2}{2a} + c \geq 0 $$
After some algebra I arrive at:
$$ \dfrac{-b^2 + 4ac}{4a} \geq 0 $$
Which clearly has my desired conclusion, but i cannot jump since $ 4a $ could be negative. Can anyone provide a proof that $ 4a > 0 $. Thanks!

Comment: If $a$ were negative, what sign would $a\lambda^2 +b\lambda +c$ have for $\lvert\lambda\rvert$ large, regardless of $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh thank you Daniel, it is an excelent hint thanks.

Comment: If $a \geq 0$ take one $\lambda$. If $a < 0 $ take another one..

Comment: @DavidCardozo I think it should be $\lambda= -\frac{b}{2a}$ that you substitute in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielFischer. 
Observation: $4a$ is positive
Proof: It will suffice to show that a is positive. Assume the contrary, that a is negative, also assume that $a \lambda^2 + b \lambda + c \geq 0 $, now choose $ \lambda = -\dfrac{c}{b} $. so that, $a \cdot {\dfrac{c^2}{b^2}} -c + c \geq 0$. 
this is equivalent to:
$a \cdot {\dfrac{c^2}{b^2}} \geq 0$. But this contradicts the fact that $ a < 0$. So our assumption is wrong a must be a possitive number.

Comment: Using the hint $|\lambda|\to \infty$ is a better approach, as your argument would fail when $b=0$.